# mongorestore failure: Error creating index mas.app: 18825

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Running mongorestore failed which never happened to me before. This time I am restoring on a primary server of a two nodes replica configuration:

```
bash-4.1$ mongorestore mas
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2015-01-16T02:01:50.692-0500 mas/app.bson
2015-01-16T02:01:50.692-0500    going into namespace [mas.app]
1 objects found
2015-01-16T02:01:50.692-0500    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "mas.app" }
Error creating index mas.app: 18825 err: "couldn't create file /mongoDB-data/mas.ns"
Aborted
```

The result of `df -h` shows there are still a lot of spaces:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       50G  3.2G   44G   7% /
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb        50G  4.4G   43G  10% /mongoDB-data
```

the original files in `/mongoDB-data`:

```
bash-4.1$ ls -l /mongoDB-data/
total 4356132
drwxr-xr-x. 2 mongod mongod       4096 Jan 16 01:42 journal
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod   67108864 Jan 16 01:42 local.0
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod 2146435072 Sep  4 20:06 local.1
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod 2146435072 Sep  4 20:06 local.2
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod   16777216 Jan 16 01:42 local.ns
drwx------. 2 root   root        16384 Sep 17 01:49 lost+found
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mongod mongod          6 Jan 16 01:42 mongod.lock
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod   67108864 Sep  4 20:06 test.0
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod   16777216 Sep  4 20:06 test.ns
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Can you create a `mas` collection another way, like by inserting documents through the shell? The error is coming from (approximately, modulo version changes) [this code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/653169a891f612afef80ec149194f11197fbaa3b/src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/catalog/namespace_index.cpp#L200), which indicates the problem is that mongod cannot open the file to create it. Does that provide any insight as to what might be going on? Is there possibly a permissions problem?